# Removing a SelectionTracker Observer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx

In my code, when an item in the recycler view is clicked, the adapter is swapped with a new one. After this, a new tracker and observer is made for the new adapter. But on long pressing, the previous observer is called instead. I'd like to know if it is possible to remove an observer from the tracker or an item touch listener from the recyclerview.

```
String id = "track" + mAdapter.getItemId(0);
    if(mAdapter.getTracker() != null) mTracker = mAdapter.getTracker();
    else {
        mTracker = new DefaultSelectionTracker.Builder<>(id, mRecyclerView,
                new MediaKeyProvider(mRecyclerView), setLookup(), StorageStrategy.createLongStorage())
                .withSelectionPredicate(SelectionPredicates.<Long>createSelectAnything())
                .build();

        mAdapter.passTracker(mTracker);
    }
    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).observeFiles(mTracker, id);
```

this is the code to create the tracker

```
public class MediaKeyProvider extends ItemKeyProvider {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

public MediaKeyProvider(RecyclerView rv){
    super(ItemKeyProvider.SCOPE_MAPPED);
    mRecyclerView = rv;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public Object getKey(int position) {
    long itemId = mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
    return itemId == -1 ? RecyclerView.NO_ID : itemId;
}

@Override
public int getPosition(@NonNull Object key) {

    VideoFileAdapter.ViewHolder vh = (VideoFileAdapter.ViewHolder)  mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId((Long) key);
    return vh == null ? RecyclerView.NO_POSITION : vh.getAdapterPosition();
}
}
```

the mediakeyprovider

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem : using only one recycler view, only changing the adapter by another one and using a SelectionTracker for some adapter but not for all of them. Somehow, the old selection traker was still interfering once it was build.
When you build the selection tracker, a link is created between the recycler view and the selection tracker with a listener. If you had the listener, you could remove it by using removeOnItemTouchListener. But you don't. So here are my solutions (in Kotlin, sorry fot that):

1. Use a new recycler view every time you create an adaptor. But I'm not a fan of this one.
2. Empty the attribute "mOnItemTouchListeners" in the recycler view. How to do that when mOnItemTouchListeners is a private member of recycler view? I'm using Extensions Method in Kotlin.

```
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    
    // This method use reflection to access a private member of a class
    // variableName : Name of the member to access
    fun <T : Any> T.getPrivateProperty(variableName : String) : Any?
    {
      return javaClass.getDeclaredField(variableName).let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        return@let field.get(this)
      }
    }
    
    // This method access the private member mOnItemTouchListeners from recyclerview and remove all the listener.
    // This method is created as an extension of the class RecyclerView
    fun RecyclerView.removeAllTouchListener()
    {
      val listenerArray = this.getPrivateProperty("mOnItemTouchListeners") as? java.util.ArrayList<RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener>
      listenerArray?.clear()
    }
```

and I can call this method like this before I change the adaptor, preferably when the previous adaptor was using the selectionTracker:

```
mRecyclerView.removeAllTouchListener()
```

mRecyclerView is a member of my class which contain the one and only RecyclerView I have.

```
private lateinit var mRecyclerView : RecyclerView
```

Hope it helps.